# How to run ssh reverse tunnel in background using python?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I need to execute the command `ssh -NTf -R 5000:localhost:22 server@ip` in the background using python. I know the command itself run in the background due to the option `-f`.

I have used python subprocess package to do this.

```
cm="ssh -NTf -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -R 5000:localhost:22 servermc@122.174.345.9"

try:
    out=sp.check_output(cm,stderr=sp.STDOUT,shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print "ddddd",e.output
```

But what happens is that the process is still in the foreground. When we run the above python code, the execution is paused at check_output command and I need to press `ctrl+c` to exit from the python code.

Also I tried the Popen and poll() functions. Using these functions, I can achieve the desired functionality but the problem is that I am not able to get the status if any error happens( like port not free or ip address error).

What I need to do is I want to run the ssh reverse tunnel in the background using python and also I need to get status whether it is run success or not from the server-side?

I can access only the server and the above script will run inside the client. Hence I can access the client through the server. If the client run this script and the status will be sent to the cloud so I can verify the status and connect to the client from the server.

Comment: Why can't you get get the status using `Popen` and `poll`? This would be the normal approach.

Comment: You would also use `communicate` with a timeout to if poll indicated the process was still running to get any error messages.

Comment: If use `communicate`, then the same problem will happen. It will pause at communicate.

Comment: That is why I said `with a timeout` to the `communicate`. Give it a 2 second timeout, expect that if everything is working fine then you will get the timeout exception. If you don't get the exception then something has probably gone wrong.

Comment: How do we give timeout to communicate function?

Comment: It is the second optional parameter see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: I was working on python2.7

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mmh sometimes glueing together basic commands is good, other times there are better solutions.

Dive into the python way: [rforward.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/rforward.py)

This script is a very good example how to use paramiko (python SSH library) and it is also a perfect working solution.
You don't need to spawn SSH, just do it all in Python.

Answer (score 0):

"Background" is purely a shell concept: what you probably want is to spawn a new process.`subprocess.Popen()` only runs a process if nothing in the python script depends on the output of the command being run.

example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ls","-lha","/"])
```

If you want to check errors or information of a process, one way is to check the logs of that process.

you can use `-E` parameter on your ssh command and append debug logs to log-file:

```
ssh -NTf -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -R 5000:localhost:22 servermc@x.x.x.x -E /tmp/ssh.log
```

After executing your ssh command with `subprocess.Popen()` then you can check the log file for any error without any pause.

[Using shell=True can be a security hazard.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

Update1: `result` variable in my script is exactly equal to `out` variable on your script. and the script will not stuck on `Popen`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

tmp_file = "/tmp/ssh.log"   #temp log file address 
cmd="ssh -NTf -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -R 5000:localhost:22 servermc@x.x.x.x -E "+tmp_file  #command to execute

def executor(command):
    try:
        file = open(tmp_file,"w+")  #create or truncates the log file if exist
        p = Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)   #execute the command
        p.wait()
        content = file.read().strip()
        file.close()
        return content
    except Exception as e:
        return e

result = executor(cmd)

print (result)
```

Comment: No, I can't use a log file since the remote client is not accessible. Basically, the client will download the ip address and port from a cloud and with which client will run the reverse tunnel so that I can access the client pc. The problem is that I will never know the reverse tunnel is started or not. So i need to get the status using python.

Comment: Yes it's a debug log and you can find out your client is connected or remote side is not accessible by parsing the log file. every thing that you need and you excepted in your python code will be in that log. -E will append standard error logs to a file.

Comment: Hey sir, I can access only the server. So i don't have any benefit in having log file on client side.

Comment: Hey sir, you must be clear and specify everything in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try autossh （for Windows，you can install cygwin's autossh)

```
import subprocess as sp
import shlex

# cm = "autossh -f -M 15580 -N root@acone3 -R 5580:127.0.0.1:5580 -C -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10"

cm = "autossh -f -M 15000 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -R 5000:localhost:22 servermc@122.174.345.9"

cm = shlex.split(cm)
try:
    out=sp.check_output(cm, stderr=sp.STDOUT,shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print("ddddd", e.output)
...
```

Notice though autossh wont exit when the python program ends. You need to explicitly kill autossh if you dont want it running. On the other hnd, as soon as the tunnel is established, you can kill autossh without affecting the tunnel -- the tunnel is in effect on an ssh session. Killing the related ssh will terminate the tunnel.